# AlertDialog - Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I would like to use alert dialog box in fragments. I'm able to execute the code in activity, but I'm not sure how to implement it in fragments.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Fragment1 extends DialogFragment {

 static Fragment1 newInstance(String title) {
     Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     args.putString("title", title);
     fragment.setArguments(args);
     return fragment;
 }

 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     String title = getArguments().getString("title");
     setCancelable (false);
     return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
     .setTitle(title)
         .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        ((a1)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                    }
         }
 )

 .create();
 } 

}
```

And in my activity I have called the dialog in following manner:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                Fragment1 dialogFragment = Fragment1.newInstance( "Error.Re-Type!");
                dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog"); 
            }
```

The above code executes without error. How could I implement this in fragment instead of activity? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

You can create AlertDialog in fragment like this. (It doesn't need explicit call)

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_save)
            .setTitle("title");
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

                //Do SOMETHING  
                }
             })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
             })
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_code)
             .show();
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. However, i would like to use the same alert dialog box in couple of fragments (reusability). Thus, it would be more efficient if I could call the alertdialog fragment (Fragment1) from various fragments. Kindly assist.